How is it possible that my DNS server is not set, but works?
Beginner's question here: My DNS server is set manually, but the IP of the DNS is missing in my configuration. Yet, I am successfully connecting to the internet via IPv4 addresses.
Why? Shouldn't I not be able to do that?

Edit:
My IPv6 is configured:


are you connected exclusively via IPv4 or also via IPv6?

Is this the only network connection on your system?

@grawity_u1686 I also have a configuration for IPv6. How do I know which one the browser uses to connect to a website?

@DanielB I also have IPv6. Added a picture.

Which browser are you using. Force Google Chrome to visit a website with IPv4 (instead of IPv6), possible? mentions with Firefox there is an option to force using IPv4 only.

@ChesterGillon Chrome. I'll try to force IPv4 and see what happens without the DNS configured.

@ChesterGillon I disabled IPv6 and I'm still able to connect to any server.

when you say "connect to the internet" do you mean just browsing the world wide web? Perhaps your browser is using "secure DNS"? i.e. DoH - does ping google.com work in the command line?

@JaromandaX My browser is using secure DNS and pinging google.com yields a response from the server.

If you disable secure DNS does the browser stop working properly

@JaromandaX Disabled DNS in the browser and it works. Pinging google.com via terminal gives me a reply: Reply from 2a00:1450:4014:80a::200e: time=12ms. So, the IPv6 is working. I changed the DNS servers (preferred & alternate to some random number) and pinging via terminal still works.

@JaromandaX OK, two things turned out: 1) I was configuring on the wrong network (I configured on Ethernet network, but I was connected via Wi-Fi). 2) The random DNS numbers I wrote in the settings of Wi-Fi turned out to be a real DNS from Google.
Now I am surprised that I can ping google.com, browser works, but nslookup server returns DNS request timed out. timeout was 2 seconds.

It is important to note that IPv6 DNS servers also enable IPv4 connectivity. // Please provide the output of ipconfig /all. You can then remove the screenshots. (It’s also pointless to censor internal IP addresses, so you could skip that.)

@DanielB I'm afraid - what if you're a hacker? :-P By the way, do you know why nslookup shows only my IPv6 address? What if I want to know both about IPv4 and IPv6 DNSs?

@DanielB Just "fixed" it by disabling the IPv6 on my network. Seems like IPv6 is preferred as I've read somewhere else on this forum.

Install Wireshark and use that to see what's actually happening.

I also have a configuration for IPv6

Then you're probably using your IPv6 DNS servers.
DNS is a generic database – a DNS server can answer the same kind of queries regardless of how it is being queried. In particular, the browser can ask an DNS server over IPv6 to query the IPv4 addresses of a website (and then connect to that website over IPv4), and vice versa, it can ask an IPv4 DNS server for the IPv6 addresses.
So it's really enough to have at least one DNS server of whichever type, and you can use it to determine both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Wireshark will likely show DNS A queries being sent over IPv6 and the replies containing A records with IPv4 addresses.

nslookup server returns DNS request timed out. timeout was 2 seconds.

Nslookup doesn't follow the same rules as the rest of the OS; it has its own DNS client (as that's really its whole purpose), and it chooses the DNS server a bit differently – not always successfully.
Try, for example, nslookup google.com 1.1.1.1 vs nslookup -q=AAAA google.com 1.1.1.1 (querying v6 addresses through IPv4) vs nslookup -q=A google.com 2606:4700:4700::1111 (querying v4 addresses through IPv6).
